# Hacking computer networks

Tags: security, networking, protocols

I am looking for a book/website/blog etc., about hacking computer networks. I don't mean things like social engineering/SQL injection/exploiting server configuration, but hacks at protocol level, like injecting packets, Ethernet level network protection etc. I am really interested in computer security, but this area is still black magic to me and I want to develop my skills in it.

I know this question may seem a little bit too general to ask on Stack Overflow, but it's really difficult to find broad materials about this narrow area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what are your programming skills, but I found these books very helpful for myself:

1. [Counter Hack Reloaded -  A Step-by-Step Guide to Computer Attacks and Effective Defenses](http://www.amazon.ca/Counter-Hack-Reloaded-Step-Step/dp/0131481045) it is more network oriented and perhaps most interesting to you
2. [Hacking : The Art of Exploitation, 2nd Edition](http://www.amazon.ca/Hacking-Art-Exploitation-Jon-Erickson/dp/1593271441/ref=pd_sim_b_4/175-1016730-8194132) has a deeper background and gives you quick introduction to machine code and C programming language. Also I like the second one because it comes with a linux ISO and source code for all examples in the book to play around with
3. [The Basics of Hacking and Penetration Testing: Ethical Hacking and Penetration Testing Made Easy](http://www.amazon.ca/Hacking-Art-Exploitation-Jon-Erickson/dp/1593271441/ref=pd_sim_b_4/175-1016730-8194132) will get you familiar with tools used for penetration testing and hacking.

Also there are plenty of website full of material, tutorials and playground, just google for computer security/hacking tutorials. For example take a look at these two ones

http://www.securitytube.net/ is a website where you can find a lot of material including video tutorials. They also offer training and certifications.

http://smashthestack.org/ is a website where you can practice your skills. It has different categories of games that comprise various levels; you start at first level and once you solve it/ hack it you get access to the next level.

Comment: Hi, unexplored, thanks for your answer. I know programming and I already know quite a lot about hacking websites etc. Now I want to learn a bit about making networks secure. For example things like how can I transfer CCTV feed and internet packets via the same network in college without worrying that students will access CCTV feed etc. The reason I am asking about it is the fact that I have networking course on my studies and I find it really boring, so I thought I will try to do something practical, so that it's more fun learning it.

Comment: @nivwusquorum Take a look at the table of contents of the first two books, you might be interested because they cover network protocols for OSI models 2-4 at some point. Based on your question I think this is what you're after

Answer (score 1):

check [darknet.org.uk](http://darknet.org.uk) 
it contains information about tools and techniques about network and database hacking.